# Tesseract fails to recognize a sequence of random English characters

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm looking for some help to configure Tesseract to identify characters in the following image (called token.png):

[image: Example of random sequence of letters and digits]

Running Tesseract with the default settings as

```
tesseract token.png output
```

results in

```
lidad3dbecsc2dedeeaedsd72bbest4 bsddo60cdetsdic?
```

On the [wiki page](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality) it is suggested to disable dictionaries

> Disabling the dictionaries Tesseract uses should increase recognition if most of your text isn't dictionary words. They can be disabled by setting both of the configuration variables load_system_dawg and load_freq_dawg to false.

However, this does not help. For example, constructing the text file `config` as

```
load_system_dawg F
load_freq_dawg F
```

and then running

```
tesseract token.png output config
```

does not improve the recognition.

Can anyone give a suggestion on how to solve this problem?

The screen shot below shows my command prompt on Windows 10

[image]

**Comment 1**

[image]

If the image, token.png as shown above, is cropped to successively build the string, it is evident that Tesseract applies some additional logic when identifying the characters. This is illustrated in the image below.

[image: Tessearct identification of strings with digits and characters]

It looks like the problem starts when letters are added to a string with digits, e.g. `174` is correctly identified but `174a` is recognized as `1ida`  If Tesseract applies additional logic, like dictionary look up, how can this functionality be switched off?

Comment: on the same wiki there are other suggestion how to improve quality. Did you tried them?

Comment: Yes, but apart from scaling, removing alpha channel and converting to black text on white background, not much improvement is gained. I added a comment to the question that illustrates that Tessearct applies some additional logic in the recognition process. There are a lot of configuration option for Tesseract, e.g. to identify single character --psm 10 needs to be set. I'm struggling to find a setting to identify a random sequence of digits and letters.

Comment: Well, in this post there are no images of code, no images of errors of output, and a minimal reproducible example is provided in the introduction. The screenshot of the terminal shows what version of Teserract that is used, together with some library information. The table is a summary of results, constructed in Inkspae, from multiple runs of the minimal reproducible example as provided in the introduction. I think I'm following the guidelines pretty closely!

Answer (score 0):

Resize image, so letters will be 30 px high, set dpi to 300, blur image, binarize:

[image]

Then:

```
tesseract KYCvf_.png - --psm 8 --oem 1
174ad3d62c3c29e9eeae03d72h6e5f47h94d060cde 78d 107
```

Comment: This looks like a big improvement, but I can not reproduce this. What version of Tesseract did you use?

Comment: tesseract 4.1 or try master with best traindata